# How do I get started with linux?

Tags: linux, software-installation, system-installation

I am a programmer but have only used Windows as the development environment till now. I work on Java. I wanted to start developing on Linux and would like to know where to start. More specifically:

- Which Linux to install on my machine?
- What are the basic requirements that I would need to know before I insert the Linux CD in my PC?
- Which packages do I need to install so that I don't have to wait for it to install while first access? I mean like JDK/ MP3 Player/ Open Office/ GCC, etc

Comment: which distribution should you use? it depends on how much you want to mess around. personally i prefer to introduce people to debian. my whole immediate family uses it now, and that's what they use. so i would recommend something *debian-based*, for sure. for instance, ubuntu is all right, and it's based on debian. as i said, i prefer plain 'ol debian.

Comment: i think I will go with Ubuntu for now. Even some of my friends recommended it

Comment: command language systematic, kernigan ritchi pike book "unix good environment" (noone whom I know haven't dealt with end-chapter tasks(problems or how to say english задания), . As knowledge depends on every command it's very importang to know the file structure basics, and specifically on your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

1. Check [Moving from Windows to Linux: Easy Steps and Resources](http://ostatic.com/blog/moving-from-windows-to-linux-easy-steps-and-resources). It's fairly new but quite good.
2. I would say if you work on Java and are new to Linux, get Ubuntu (with Unity, GNOME or KDE or even XFCE). It's user friendly, has a huge user base and IMHO its the ideal Linux to shift from Windows to Linux. You may opt for any Linux. Finally, if you use the Terminal, everything is *almost* the same. One major difference between the BSD camp, Debian/Ubuntu camp and Fedora/ScientificLinux camp is the way packages are handled. Before I knew it, I was a fan of the apt-get mode and it's hard for me to shift now. But that's a personal preference. If you want a **real** system, which is absolutely not dumbed down, you may want Arch Linux, Gentoo or FreeBSD. The options are virtually endless. You can go to [distrowatch.com](http://distrowatch.com/) to find out relative properties of different *NIXs.
3. I don't think there are any special requirements. If you can run Windows XP/7, Ubuntu will run just as well. (Maybe better). This might take some tweaking but it's a one time investment.
4. I don't understand your question. Are you asking about the "must-haves" of Linux? If you do choose Ubuntu, then ubuntu-restricted-extras is a "must-have" and a couple of others. Please clarify your question and I'll try to fill in.

Comment: ok will edit my question

Comment: Considering your edit, I can't help but to recommend http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=mint

Comment: whoa! thats a huge list!

Comment: What list? It is one distribution with many versions. Just download the latest one and give it a drive.

Comment: No way is `ubuntu-restricted-extras`, or any other proprietary software a "must-have". If anything I would recommend forcibly exorcising these from usage.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you, but realizing that takes about 3 months of Linux usage after leaving Windoze. Its good to have initially but should be booted out later.